# Using OpenStreet map in website with LeafletJS to display heapmap

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

Is it possible to download OSM or embed OSM and use leafletjs on top of it to display heat map?

I have searched a lot and could not find anything related. I wanted something like this form Google Maps.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

I did find the mapbox but we need to pay them. I need something open source.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create heatmaps with Leaflet by using the various available plugins:

http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#heatmaps

However, you'll need some vector data to build a heatmap, not just the tilelayer. If you want to use OpenStreetMap to get your data, try a service like http://overpass-turbo.eu/ to download the things you want in this format.